# Signing in using FirebaseUI doesn't back out of webview and throws error

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am trying to allow users to sign in using a Google account by following the FirebaseUI tutorial. When I get in the browser vc that is presented I am just taken to the Google home page and am never logged in. The only option is to click done with returns the error `Error Domain=com.google.GIDSignIn Code=-5 "The user canceled the sign-in flow." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The user canceled the sign-in flow.}`

This is really frustrating and is backing up my whole team since we can't get auth working, so does anyone know how to fix this?

Note I am using iOS 9. I'm not sure if that may have to do with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ran into same problem from the Firecast videos, you need to add a call back in AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
  openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
        sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
        annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
```

Reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I was using **react-native-google-signin** and **react-native-fbsdk** both. Found solution in, pointed issue on  [**react-native-google-signin**](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/issues/152).

The problem is react-native-google-signin conflicts with facebook sdk in AppDelegate.m.

**To fix this, edit AppDelegate.m as follows:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  if ([url.scheme hasPrefix:@"fb"]) {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                       annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
            ];


  }else{
    return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                               sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                      annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];


      }
}
```

And this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {

if (url.scheme?.hasPrefix("fb"))! {
   return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, options: options) 
}
else{
   return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,annotation: [:])
   }
}
```